# bash fork subprocess with command link $(cmd1|cmd2)

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

#### Question

I wrote some command lines like `output=$(cmd1|cmd2)` in a bash script file (aaaa.sh) and found a subprocess generated.

#### code in the file aaaa.sh

```
echo "The name of this file is $(basename $0)."
echo "The pid of this program is $$."

echo -e '\n---- 0 ----'
echo -e 'CMD: ps -ef | grep "aaaa.sh" | grep -v grep'
ps -ef | grep "aaaa.sh" | grep -v grep

echo -e '\n---- 1 ----'
echo -e 'CMD: ps -ef | grep "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "bbbb" | grep -v grep'
ps -ef | grep "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "bbbb" | grep -v grep

echo -e '\n---- 2 ----'
echo -e 'CMD: pgrep -a "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "bbbb"'
pgrep -a "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "bbbb"

echo -e '\n---- 3 ----'
echo -e 'CMD: pgrep -a "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "$$"'
pgrep -a "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "$$"

echo -e '\n---- 4 ----'
echo -e 'CMD: output=$(ps -ef | grep "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "bbbb" | grep -v grep)'
output=$(ps -ef | grep "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "bbbb" | grep -v grep)
echo -e "$output"

echo -e '\n---- 5 ----'
echo -e 'CMD: output=$(ps -ef | grep "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "$$" | grep -v grep)'
output=$(ps -ef | grep "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "$$" | grep -v grep)
echo -e "$output"

echo -e '\n---- 6 ----'
echo -e 'CMD: output=$(pgrep -a "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "bbbb")'
output=$(pgrep -a "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "bbbb")
echo -e "$output"

echo -e '\n---- 7 ----'
echo -e 'CMD: output=$(pgrep -a "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "$$")'
output=$(pgrep -a "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "$$")
echo -e "$output"

echo -e '\n---- 8 ----'
echo -e 'CMD: output=$(pgrep -a "aaaa.sh")'
output=$(pgrep -a "aaaa.sh")
echo -e "$output"
```

#### output

[output](http://i4.bvimg.com/600088/6c4b8ceb2b5e0575.png)

#### Question

There is a subprocess generated in 4,5,6 and 7. why?

Comment: If output is text, please just include it in the question, questions that rely on clicking links to understand the problem are discouraged

Comment: just paste your preformatted text, highlight it and the hit ctrl+k (cmd+k for mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shells typically execute command substitution (`$()`) and command piping (`|`) in subshells.

```
output=$(ps -ef | grep "aaaa.sh" | grep -v "$$" | grep -v grep)
```

This statement actually results in the creation of five processes--one for the command substitution subshell, and one more for each of the commands in the pipeline.

From the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

Edit - To try this out for yourself run the following:

```
$ echo $BASHPID >&2 | echo $BASHPID >&2 | echo $BASHPID
```

We can see a different PID for each subshell in the pipeline.

Comment: yeah?!!! Five processes ... Have you noticed the command below '---- 1 ----':"ps -ef|grep "aaaa.sh"|grep -v "bbbb"|grep -v grep", this shows only one process, the current process!

Comment: We only see the current process because `ps` executes first at the beginning of the pipeline, so it doesn't know about the processes that haven't started yet. Try this: `echo $BASHPID >&2 | echo $BASHPID >&2 | echo $BASHPID`. We can see a different PID for each subshell in the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you! The env "BASHPID" do help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because of

> $(...)

Quote from bash man page:

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name.  There are two forms:
>                $(command)
>         or
>                `command`.
>         Bash  performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.  Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during
>          word splitting.

So, you actually see the subshell created to execute your commands

Comment: Please look at the command below '---- 8 ----': output=$(pgrep -a "aaaa.sh"), there is only one line in "$output".